# For Loop inside Function, Array Enumeration

Tags: javascript, loops

Having some difficulty with this code for my assignment.

I'm supposed to create two functions.

1. the first function is  called `calledInLoop` that will accept one parameter and log the parameter.

   ```
   calledInLoop = function (parameter) {
       console.log(parameter);
   }
   ```
2. the second function is called `loopThrough` that will accept an array, loop through each, and invoke the `calledInLoop` function. The result should be each element of the array is console logged.

   ```
   loopThrough = function (array) {
       for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
           calledInLoop(array[i]);
       };
   }

   myArray = ['dog', 'bird', 'cat', 'gopher'];
   ```

`console.log(loopThrough(myArray));` returns each element on its own `console.log` line but then returns `undefined`. Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

The call to `console.log` in `console.log(loopThrough(myArray));` is **only** printing out `undefined`. It does this because `loopThrough` does not return anything, so it defaults to `undefined`.

The elements in the array are printed by a call to `calledInLoop` in `loopThrough`, which in turn calls `console.log`.

Answer (score 0):

Your loopThrough function does not return any value when called. Hence it's return value is undefined.

```
loopThrough = function (array) { 
       for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) 
             calledInLoop(array[i])
       return 1
 }
```

Now this will return you 1.
Similarly you can return any other values.

Comment: got it. what would i end the loopThrough function  with?

Comment: It's okay if your function does not return any value. You can return true or 0 ( most common practice ) if you want just to show that your function returned something